# one to many mapping in hibernate : Referring two different properties to a single column

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping

[This scenario is for illustration]
I have certain products, and each product can have comments. Comments are of two types, **general comments**(GC) and **product comments** (PC).

*Sample Tables*

> **PRODUCT**
>
> ID      NAME
>
> ---
>
> 1       APPLE

--

> **PRODUCT_COMMENTS**
>
> COMMENT_ID |   COMMENT   |                COMMENT_TYPE
>
> ---
>
> 1   |       IPHONE IS GOOD | PC
>
> 2    |      IPAD LOOKS GOOD |GC
>
> 3      |   GENERAL COMMENT| GC
>
> 4   |       PRODUCT COMMENT |PC

Assume that there is a foreign key from Product table to Product_comment table.

And I have a couple of classes mapping to these tables.

Product class and ProductComment class

Product class has a one-to-may relationship with ProductComment class.

```
  public class Product {
     private Long id;

     private String productName;

     private List<ProductComments> productComments;

     private List<ProductComments> generalComments;

    .....

   }
```

Now my problem is,  **there are two separate list of comments** (differentiated by the comment_type).

When I say

```
      Product p = (Product)session.load(Product.class, new Long(1));
```

**Is it possible to fetch the generalComments and productComments properly** ? In the above example

generalComments list should contain ['IPAD LOOKS GOOD','GENERAL COMMENT'] and the productComments list should contain  ['IPHONE IS GOOD','PRODUCT COMMENT'].

What sort of mapping should be done to achieve the above thing ?

Edit :

We use Hibernate 3.0 and hbm mapping files(not annotations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [@Where](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Where.html) annotation. You can give SQL condition to limit which ones will be chosen. In your example it goes roughly as follows:

```
@Where(clause="COMMENT_TYPE = 'PC'")
private List<ProductComments> productComments;

@Where(clause="COMMENT_TYPE = 'GC'")
 private List<ProductComments> generalComments;
```

Be aware that this limit values loaded from database, but not the values written to these lists. You have still via program logic control which kind of comments are written to these lists.

Comment: We use hbm mapping files. Is an equivalent of @where available for xml mapping ? We use Hibernate 3.0

Comment: try looking at the hibernate documentation.  I believe it's a "where" attribute on the "list" element in your mapping.  <list where="..."><many-to-one ...></many-to-one></list>

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would choose to use inheritance for the sake of readability and type safety.
That means, create `Comment.class` `GeneralComment.class` and `ProductComment.class`.
You can choose 2 ways for dealing with the hierarchy :

1. Actual inheritance. each class represents an equivalent table joined by PK.
2. Object inheritance. discriminate the `Comment.class` values into the two other entities using a discriminator column :

on the `Comment.class` :

`<discriminator column="discriminator_column"  type="discriminator_type"  force="true|false"  insert="true|false"  formula="arbitrary sql expression"  />`

on each subclass :

`<subclass name="ClassName"  discriminator-value="discriminator_value"  proxy="ProxyInterface"  lazy="true|false"  dynamic-update="true|false" dynamic-insert="true|false" entity-name="EntityName" node="element-name" extends="SuperclassName"> <property .... /> ..... </subclass>`

Now your code can look like :

```
public class Product {
 private Long id;

 private String productName;

 private List<ProductComments> productComments;

 private List<GeneralComments> generalComments;

.....
```

}